# Build REST API top of GraphQL API

Tags: api, rest, graphql

I'm trying to find a library or something like that, where I can define REST endpoints top on a 3rd party GraphQL API queries mutations.

I found `https://github.com/sisense/graphql2rest` and `https://github.com/Urigo/SOFA` but both of these libs are required to be the graphql in exact same place.

Is there any free to use lib for that? Or I have to write an own, because there is no other option.

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: What do you mean with 'on top' exactly. They don't really stack. Do you mean it like a proxy? or 2 styles of APIs on a single host?

Comment: Not in a single host. I want a standalone API for it. I mean for example the GraphQL api has queries like post(id: Int) : Post and posts(page: Int, limit : Int): [Post] and I would like define rest endpoints like GET: /posts is for the posts query and GET: /post/:id is for post query etc etc. But if I write these manual for every query and for every mutation then it will be mess. And I did not found yet a generic solution for it.

Comment: Ok, so you would like to expose a feature in _both_ REST and GraphQL, is that correct?

Comment: yes, but the rest has to be standalone (separated project)

Comment: I see, i think one of the problems with this is that they are fundamentally different models. So writing something that automatically re-exposes and existing GraphQL endpoint is REST is always going to be the worst of 2 worlds. They need to be designed separately if you want a good REST and a good GraphQL api.